# jquery pulling a dynamic value for an ajax data value

Tags: jquery

How would I go about pulling '&something=' if there is no static value to pull? How would combine 'commentBox' and var id if that is a possible solution?

```
// process addComment()
jQuery(".textbox1").keydown(function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) {
      addComment(this);
  }
});

function addComment() {
  var id = jQuery(e).attr("id");
  var newId = id.replace("commentBox-", "");
  var dataString = '&something=' + newId;
  // proceed with ajax call
}
```

Comment: You are passing a value to addComment(), but this function has no parameters defined.

Comment: Try changing your `addComment` function like `function addComment(_this) {  var id = _this.id;//Your code...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the current object (the textbox where the enter key was pressed) to the addComment function.

```
$(function(){
 $(".textbox1").keydown(function(event) {
  var item=$(this);
  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) {
      addComment(item);
  }
});
  });
function addComment(item) {
  var id = item.attr("id");
  var newId = id.replace("commentBox-", "");
  var dataString = '&something=' + newId;
  alert(dataString );
}
```

JsFiddle Sample http://jsfiddle.net/YAQpc/8/

Comment: It's still putting &something= and not putting the value of var id in it

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby: Is your text box have an id in the format commentBox-id ? check the jSFiddle sample i provided

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".textbox1").on('keyup', function(event) {
  var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (code==13) { addComment(this); }
});

function addComment(elm) {
  var newId = elm.id.replace("commentBox-", "");
  var dataString = '&something=' + newId;
  // proceed with ajax call
}
```